# Integrating admob interstitial ads in libgdx

Tags: java, android, libgdx, admob, ads

I am developing a game in libgdx, I want to Integrate admob interstitial ads in my game,
someone have any tutorial that explained how to do that in libgdx? I try to find one, but I came with no success.

Sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement the interstitial ads in the android game's MainActivity. Follow the libgdx [official guide](https://github.com/TheInvader360/tutorial-libgdx-google-ads/commit/0a5ea376d4eb92b8e87c13a03245adb40b53e811) for implementing interstitial ads